# Как запретить индексацию?

Tags: robots.txt

Помогите составить инструкцию в файл robots.txt так, чтобы удалить из поиска страницы:

```
1111.ru/?electronics=1
1111.ru/?electronics=2
1111.ru/?auto=1 и т.п.
```

Но при этом чтобы не были затронуты страницы по вот таким адресам:

```
1111.ru/electronics/1
1111.ru/electronics/2
1111.ru/auto/1
```

Если кто-то может подсказать другой вариант, расскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если на сайте используется ЧПУ 1111.ru/auto/1, а обычная ссылка 1111.ru/?auto=1 нигде не светится, то робот проиндексирует только ЧПУ-ссылку.

Comment: Теперь да, на сайте только ЧПУ, но раньше не было. Так вот яшка уже в течении 2 месяцев шлет людей на старые адреса, а новые не воспринимает. Ни одной новой ссылки не съел.
Зато с гуглом все в порядке.

Comment: @SKYnetRTX, а редирект со старых на новые не пробовали?

Comment: да, уже больше месяца стоит редирект в одном из разделов. (он приносит большую часть трафика), а яшка не берет новый урл, все старый держит.